# AngualrJS OIDC Client Silent Renew page

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, identityserver4, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I am struggling to understand how this silent renew process works. as per what I Read I understood that the html page will be kept in an iframe and it keeps pinging server for renewing token.

I have an angular application, typically we package everything into one simple index.html file and rest will be inserted based on route (ui-router, template caching).

So In my context, should we keep this html packaged? or should it be separate html page lives alongside index.html?

Comment: I figured out this, basically the implementation I went with is, 
copy the oidc file and silent renew html pages to root of the application using webpack and when pointed silent renew redirect url to the respective html page. So this way I did not have to load entire bundle and this is light weight.